# jQuery - detect mouse out of new element

Tags: jquery

I've built a menu using jQuery which shows a new element fading in when the user hovers the mouse over the element and fades it out when they move the mouse away. Now, I've moved the element up so it covers the original element which is causing the problem that the second hover event is triggered when the new element is placed over the top. What would be the best method to ignore the new element and only fade out once the mouse has moved out of the bound of the original element?

Here's the code:

```
$('#menuitem').hover(function() {
    $('#menu').append('<span id="hover_'+$(this).attr('rel')+'" class="hover"></span>');
}, function() {
    $('#hover_'+$(this).attr('rel')).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```

Now, the `#menu` item is a anchor with some text in it, when the mouse is over it, a new element (`.hover`) should appear on top and should fade out once the mouse leaves the original menu item.

What's currently happening is that the new element appears and fades out immediately as the second hover function is triggered when the new item is added on top of the original anchor.

Thanks,
J

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of your code with this. It could be done a number of different ways.

Comment: Edited to include sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the listener:

```
$(element_here).unbind(); // If you used $(element_here).bind(); or .hover();
$(element_here).die(); // If you used $(element_here).live();
```

Then add it back once the mouse has left the old element.

There is more likely a better solution than this, but we probably need to see an example of the code that you're using before we can make any better attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution I've found in cases like this is to do the binding inline in the HTML. It may not be the prettiest way to do it, but many times (in my experience) its way easier to have the binding inline than trying to worry about racing with `undind()`. This is obviously not a full example but it should be enough to get you started:

Note: I'm not sure what kind of data you were storing in the `rel` attr so I just used the word in place of whatever that would be.

HTML

```
<li id="menuitem" onmouseover="fadeOut(rel)">bar</li>
```

JS

```
function fadeOut(rel){
$('#hover_'+rel).fadeOut()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the issue I'm having is that I don't want it to fade out until the mouse has let the area of the element. It's currently fading out too soon when the new element is placed on top.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, the same code would work for that just substitute `onmouseout` for `onmouseover`.